# How do I trim down an existing dataset with several features to a smaller dataset containing only the attributes selected by Boruta?

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, feature-selection

I am trying to use a random forest classifier on some proteomics data. The current dataset that I'm using has in excess of 1000 features and I've decided to use Boruta for feature selection. Boruta selected 31 features and I intend to use only these selected features to train my classifier and predict my test set. Is there a way that I can create a new dataset containing only the selected features from Boruta?

Here's a snip of my code:

```
set.seed(223)
boruta.train <- Boruta(
Class ~ ., data = training, doTrace = 2) 
print(getSelectedAttributes(boruta.train))

[1] "P22087"                                                                                                                                      
[2] "P54886.P54886.2"                                                                                                                             
[3] "Q4V328.Q4V328.4.B1B0M1.Q4V328.2.Q4V328.3"                                                                                                    
[4] "Q9BZJ0.Q5JY65.Q9BZJ0.3.Q9BZJ0.4.Q9BZJ0.5"                                                                                                    
[5] "Q9NXF1.Q9NXF1.2.B7Z9D5"                                                                                                                      
[6] "Q6P158.H7C109.Q6P158.2.F8WAZ3.Q6P158.3.C9J207"                                                                                               
[7] "Q9NVV4.Q5T851"                                                                                                                               
[8] "O00330.E9PB14.E9PBP7.H0YD97.E9PLU0.E9PRI6"                                                                                                   
[9] "Q99575.E5RK39"
[10] "Q96ED9.Q96ED9.2"                                                                                                                             
[11] "Q02790.F5H1U3.H0YFG2.F5H120"                                                                                                                 
[12] "Q9P258"                                                                                                                                      
[13] "O00267.O00267.2"                                                                                                                             
[14] "O14497.O14497.2.O14497.3.H0Y488.Q96SM7.H0YCU6.H0YEW5"                                                                                        
[15] "Q9Y265.Q9Y265.2.E7ETR0.H7C4G5.H7C4I3.J3QLR1"                                                                                                 
[16] "Q6PKG0.Q6PKG0.3.E5RH50.H0YC33.H0YC73.H0YBM7.H0YAN4.E5RHK4.H0YBJ5.H0YBR8"                                                                     
[17] "P26641.B4DTG2.E7EMT2"                                                                                                                        
[18] "Q7Z6Z7.Q7Z6Z7.3.Q7Z6Z7.2.H0Y5W0.Q5H962.H0Y659.H0Y7U1.Q5H963.A5YM72.2"                                                                        
[19] "Q96QR8"                                                                                                                                      
[20] "Q13526.Q49AR7"                                                                                                                               
[21] "P62256.C9JZY6.A4D1L6.C9JZG9.H7C4M9.C9J8Q9"                                                                                                   
[22] "P36405"                                                                                                                                      
[23] "O00264.B7Z1L3"                                                                                                                               
[24] "P04792.F8WE04.C9J3N8"                                                                                                                        
[25] "O14558"                                                                                                                                      
[26] "P09211.A8MX94"                                                                                                                               
[27] "P01033.Q5H9A7.H0Y789.Q5H9B5.B4DJK3.Q5H9B4"                                                                                                   
[28] "P53350.I3L387.I3L2H5"                                                                                                                        
[29] "Q96JB2.Q96JB2.2"                                                                                                                             
[30] "Q13409.2.F8W8S0.Q13409.Q13409.5.Q13409.3.Q13409.6.B7ZA04.E7EV09.E7EQL5.E7EMU4.E7ETL8.E7EQU2.E7ESD3.E7ET01.E7ERH4.E7ERR6.E9PGG1.E7EUM4.E7EU01"
[31] "G5E9Q6.P35080.2.C9J0J7"
```

How do I delete the "unimportant" features from my dataset? Is this feature built into Boruta?

I'm hoping that I would be able to perform the following on the new data set with selected features from Boruta:

```
model <- randomForest(formula = Class ~ ., ntree = 500, mtry = 7, data =    training)
model
# Predict and classify the test set
pred <- predict(model, newdata = testing)
table(pred, testing$Class)
```

*EDIT*

I tried

```
data2 <- data[,getSelectedAttributes(boruta.train)]
```

to pare my data set, but in the process, I lost my first Column "Sample" which I used to classify my samples. Initially my data set looked like this:

```
names(data)
[1] "Sample"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
[2] "F8W9N1.Q9UHK6.D6RB81.Q9UHK6.2.Q9UHK6.4"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
[3] "P24043"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
[4]   "B4DMU0.P32322.E2QRB3.A6NFM2.J3KQ22.J3QKT4.J3QL24.J3QL32.J3QLK9.J3QL23.J3QR88.J3QRZ0.J3QKT3.J3KTA8.J3KSA9"                                                                                                                                                                    
[5] "Q53FZ2.H3BSM0.E7ETR5.Q53FZ2.2.H3BVD5.H3BV29.H3BT38.H3BUF2.H3BR33"                                                                                                                                                                                                            
[6] "Q9Y666.H0YB78.Q9Y666.2"
```

And I would like to retain the "Sample" column after I've used the Boruta selected features. I tried this but the output isn't correct:

```
 data2$Sample <- data[,getSelectedAttributes(boruta.train)]
```

*EDIT*

I was able to restore the Sample column using this simple fix

```
data2$Sample <- data$Sample
```

Comment: It looks like `getSelectedAttributes` gives you a vector with the names of the selected columns. If that's right, then you can reduce your original data set (say, `df`) with a simple `df[,getSelectedAttributes(boruta.train)]`.

Comment: I tried this and it worked     .dim(data)
[1]   36 1225
> newdata <- data[,getSelectedAttributes(boruta.train)]
> dim(newdata)
[1] 36 29 Thank you!